# Bash error This: command not found

Tags: linux, bash

Im just beginning to learn bash and am attempting to write a script that accepts two words as arguments and prints out the portion of the given file between the line where the first word is found and where the second word is found for example if my `test.txt` file looks like:

```
This is a line of text
This is another line of text
this is the third one
Another one right here
```

And i run the program with `./prog.bash test.txt This one` it should return lines 1,2 and 3 since we find the word This at line one and the word one at line 3. My current script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=$1
a=$(grep -n -m1 "$2" "$filename" | cut -f 1 -d':') #find first occurence of word1 and use that to cut the line number of word
b=$(grep -n -m1 "$3" "$filename" | cut -f 1 -d':') #find first occurence of word2 and use that to cut the line number of word
lines=$(($b-$a)+1)
thing= $(head -n"${b}" "$filename" | tail -n"${lines}") #Print out b lines from beginning and then print $(lines) lines from bottom of that
echo $a
echo $b
echo $lines
echo $thing
exit
```

Now i get an error saying

> ./prog.bash: line 6: This: command not found

Since the only commands on that line are `head` and `tail` i looked where my path was and where they were located and I came up with:

```
$PATH = 
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

head = /usr/bin/head

tail = /usr/bin/tail
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 6 should be

```
thing=$(head -n"${b}" "$filename" | tail -n"${lines}") #Print out b lines from beginning and then print $(lines) lines from bottom of that
```

Without space after `=`